# Display related info in redirected page without reloading when clicked on particular image or text

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to explain my doubt with an example

Lets say i got movie database where i stored info related to particular movie in each row.

Lets say i got two rows in my database

1) Titanic     1997         Romance, Thriller

2) Avatar      2009         Action, Fantasy, Romance

I have homepage.php where movie images with text below it are displayed as gallery and i got a movieinfo.php page where all the info about movie is present.

Ex :

Title : "Titanic"

Release Date : "1997"

Genre : "Romance, Thriller"

etc

Now when i clicked on titanic image(which is in my homepage.php) it should redirect to movieinfo.php and get the titanic info from database with id and should display related info of titanic in those double quotes " " (nothing should be changed in movieinfo.php other than those values placed in double quotes).

And same should be happen when i click on avatar image

I tried to change that info with php but it gets last imported data from database and displays that info.
After some research i found that it is possible with AJAX but i am absolute beginner with AJAX. Need someone's help to know the logic and it will be more helpful if you give me small code with above example

Thank you

I have created example code so that i can get help from you

Lets say this is my moviedb.php(which contains movie insertion php code)

```
<?php
$title = "";
$releaseDate = "";
$Genre = "";


if (isset($_POST['submit-btn'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
        $errors['title'] = 'Title required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['genre'])) {
        $errors['genre'] = 'Genre required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['releaseDate'])) {
        $errors['releaseDate'] = 'Release Date required';
    }

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $releaseDate = $_POST['releaseDate'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];

    // Check if title already exists
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE movie_title='$title' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $errors['title'] = "Title already exists";
    }

    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO movie SET movie_title=?, movie_releaseDate=?, movie_genre=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $title, $releaseDate, $genre);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $movie_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['movie_id'] = $movie_id;
            $_SESSION['title'] = $title;
            $_SESSION['releaseDate'] = $releaseDate;
            $_SESSION['genre'] = $genre;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Movie has been inserted succesfully!';
            header('location: movieinsertion.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not insert movie";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

This is movieinsertion.php (which contains form to enter movie details to database )

```
    <form action="movieinsertion.php" method="post">
      <label for="title"><b>Title : </b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="title" required>

      <label for="releaseDate"><b>Release Date : </b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Release Date" name="releaseDate" required>

      <label for="genre"><b>Genre : </b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Genre" name="genre" required>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="submit-btn" id="submit-btn">Movie insert</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This is movieinfo.php (where movie info is displayed)

```
      <p class="movieinfo">
        <b style="font-size:20px; color:tomato;"> Title : </b> <?php echo $_SESSION['title']; ?> 
        <br/>
        <b> Release Date : </b>  <?php echo $_SESSION['releaseDate']; ?>
        <br/>
        <b> Genre : </b>  <?php echo $_SESSION['genre']; ?>
       </p>
```

This is homepage.php (Where movie images are placed using anchor tag)

```
    <div class="movieimg">
       <a href = "movieinfo.php"> <img src="assets/image-1.jpg" alt="Titanic" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Titanic</div></a>
    </div>

    <div class="movieimg">
       <a href = "movieinfo.php"> <img src="assets/image-2.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Avatar</div></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Without seeing the relevant code, the question is too abstract and broad.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  I have created a sample code which may be helpful for you to answer my question. and Thank you for response

Comment: Hello any one out there who can help me with this problem